# Current flow in long channel MOSFET in saturation

Tags: mosfet

Why doesn't the current in long channel nMOS decrease with drain voltage due to pinch off that takes place when gate voltage at a point in the channel is less than the threshold.

Comment: In a different universe it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question could use some updating as it is not clear; however, if you have a "long channel" device, you are assuming that you do not have drain dependencies due to charge sharing at the drain/source edges.  Also, you do not have "pinch off" when you are less than threshold.  You have a barrier in subthreshold, so that the current will be completely dependent on the barrier height, as this is the nature of drift (subthreshold) operation of the device.

[image: common source nFET]

In the picture above, \$\Psi_S\$ is the surface potential, and the barrier is \$\Phi_{SC}\$, so the current is fixed by \$\Phi_{SC}\$.  The voltage you see at the drain will be decreased by the length of the device.

The [EKV model](http://ekv.epfl.ch/) is uses pinch-off for the boundary between drift and diffusion transport, so I you really care about the effects of pinch-off, I would start there.

Alternatively, what you might be looking for is the effect of pinch-off at the drain.  The resistance of this region can be completely neglected for most purposes. You have a gate to substrate voltage to invert the channel, but the drain voltage will tie back into the channel edge and give you a "not quite" inverted region in the \$V_{ds} > V_{gs}-V_t\$.

I would sit down and start doing some band diagrams and the solution should come to you fairly quickly.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I am expecting the answer in simple terms. Your band diagram doesn't seem to help. Also it would be easier if you apply to a single nMOS rather than the CMOS.

Comment: CMOS is just complimentary MOS, so the nMOS band I supplied is adequate.  Good luck with your academic endeavors.

Comment: The band you supplied is pMOS.  In any case your explanation is not clear to me.

Comment: That is a conduction band diagram of a nMOS transistor, which means it is an energy diagram instead of a potential diagram.   Invert it for a potential diagram.  Physicists diagram vs. EE diagram.   I would start by drawing a "zero bias" condition and then go from there using whatever you book uses as a reference.